# Create multiple forms on one page for different models in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

> I have 2 models: User and UserInfo with relation 1-1 (One user have
>   one userinfo).
>
> **User(id)** is *primary key* for **User** and **UserInfo(user_id)**
>   is both *foreign key* and *primary key* for **UserInfo**.
>
> 2 models have the same attribute: email, password.
>
> I want to insert 'user_id', 'email', 'password' to UserInfo when add
>   new User.
>
> But it seems can insert to UserInfo although User is successful saved.
>
> I think it stop when ($this->User->UserInfos->save($userinfo)) run.

Anybody can help?
--Here is my code---

```
///**
 * Add method
 *
 * @return void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
 */
public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $userinfo = $this->Users->UserInfos->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            $userinfo = $this->Users->UserInfos->patchEntity($userinfo, [
                'user_id' => $user['User']['id'],
                'email' => $user['User']['email'],
                'password' => $user['User']['password'],
            ]); 
            if ($this->User->UserInfos->save($userinfo)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The userinfo has been saved.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user', 'userinfo'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user', 'userinfo']);
}


//Code in add.php
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->radio('user_type',
        [
            ['value' => '0', 'text' => 'Personal'],
            ['value' => '1', 'text' => 'Company'],
        ]);
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('status', ['value' => '0']);
        echo $this->Form->hidden('authority', ['value' => '0']);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using array notation to reference `$user`, when property notation is more reliable? What does your `$userinfo` variable look like after the patchEntity call? I'm guessing it's not what you're expecting. Are you replicating email and password fields between the two tables? (If so, why? If not, why aren't you using dot notation when creating the form fields?) Many things about this make it look like you haven't really read the relevant parts of the manual.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I'm very new in cakePHP framework, can you help me for that? Show me where I can find the thing you said. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may take the [Bookmarker Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html) as a reference because in the tutorial, new `Tags` are created while new `Bookmarks` is created. You can consider this as an idea of your `UserInfo` creation.

Well I am new to CakePHP too but have this idea for your case.

In your controller, controller\UserController, the action `add()` creates User entity:

```
public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->User->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']); // same controller's index action, or you can set others
            }
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

In your model, `model\Table\UserTable.php`, create a function called `afterSave()` which creates UserInfo [after User entity is saved](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave)

```
$this->UserInfo->newEntity();
```

So inside `newEntity()`, you actually set some data which User doesn't have and UserInfo has, besides user_id (user_id should be set if you have already set up the [associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) of them)

I strongly recommend to follow all basic tutorials.

Remarks: I suggest you define model's name clearly as [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) should be an important topic for CakePHP's developer. So for the above codes/filenames I typed, could be wrong if they don't match your case exactly. e.g. Users / Users / UsersInfo / UserInfo etc.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, I have tried as your ideas. But it's still have error:

Undefined variable: userinfo [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 84]

I'm sure that I have already set up the associations of them. With **belongTos** in UserInfosTable and **hasOne** in UsersTable.
Btw, 2 table's name is "users" and "user_infos" following conventions...

Comment: It's my mistake, should be `$this->User->save($user)`. Answer edited.

Comment: I know that mistake and of course I try to change, but it still just save for only users table, not for user_infos table....

Comment: @つまんない
//in UserInfosTable
{$this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);}
>// In UsersTable
$this->hasOne('UserInfos', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);

Comment: it's not working. Only save into users table. Nothing happens with user_infos table...

Comment: I think its about email or password field? Maybe try to set them null in UserInfo.

Comment: How can I set them null? I try to change 
    $validator
//            ->add('email', 'valid', ['rule' => 'email'])
//            ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
//            ->notEmpty('email');
            ->allowEmpty('email'); 
    And change in table design (allow null).
But nothing change

Comment: What else do you have in UserInfo? I know you have user_id, email, password only. Try to make the task more simpler, let say `user_id` and `message`, only. And see if `$this->UserInfo->newEntity(['message' => 'hello']);` works?

Comment: Do you have Skype account? Can we discuss more on skype?